# How can I check if a certain column (using WHERE) exists in MySQL using Python's mysql-connector?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

So I'd create multiple columns with ids that are not in order and I'd want to check if one of the ids is already in use, for example before doing `UPDATE .. SET .. WHERE id = 123;` I'd like to be able to check if the column with `id=123` already exists or if I'd have to create a new one. I'm using mysql-connector with python 3.8 for this.

Comment: Do you mean column or do you mean row? If you mean row then you can perform a select query like so. `select * from table where id = 123`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement. Regardless of the programming language or the mysql connector, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query will try to insert the provided data and if the data exists (based on unique indexes) will update them.